# Entity Framework - Insert with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, insert-update

Apologies if there is clear answer for this somewhere. But I can't insert into a simple table due to it containing a foreign key.

#### Task Table

TaskId (PK)

Description

StatusId (FK)

Into which I try to insert like so:

```
        Task t = new Task();
        t.Id = 1234;
        t.Title = "foo";
        t.Status = db.Status.ToList().First();
```

But get an updateException error:

*A relationship is being added or deleted from an AssociationSet 'FK_Task_Status'. With cardinality constraints, a corresponding 'Task' must also be added or deleted.*

How can I insert into this table?

Cheers

....

Found my issue....

My schema was wrong. When I created my foreign key I pointed it to the wrong field. Had a look in SQL profiler, saw this:

> SELECT 
>   1 AS [C1], 
>   [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
>   [Extent1].[Descr] AS [Descr], 
>   [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1]
>   FROM  [dbo].[Status] AS [Extent1]
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Task] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]

Which should be this (joining on statusId not id):

> SELECT 
>   1 AS [C1], 
>   [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
>   [Extent1].[Descr] AS [Descr], 
>   [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1]
>   FROM  [dbo].[Status] AS [Extent1]
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Task] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[StatusId]

Silly me ;)

Answer (score 2):

in .net framework 4.0 u can use this simple way:

```
 Task t = new Task();
    t.Id = 1234;
    t.Title = "foo";
    t.StatusId = 5678;
```

reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using "Entity Framework 1.0" (the version that was, until today, the most current) you have the right idea- get the Status from the database to set on the Task.  Are you sure you're actually getting a Status entity with the syntax you're using above?

Step through your code to make sure the reference on the Task entity is being set to an actual materialized Status entity.

Comment: Hey Dave. Debugging through the code, I am getting a valid status entity assigned to t.Status.....
Oh dear, just found my problem. Foreign Key is linking to the wrong field. Will update my question. Thanks for your answer, it made me look more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
        Task t = new Task();
        t.Id = 1234;
        t.Title = "foo";
        t.Status.EntityKey = new EntityKey("tblStatus","StatusId",t.StatusID);
```

hope this will work